# HTML5 visualisations in mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, html5-audio

I am trying to make use of a few visualization libraries for a mobile app I am making (with phonegap).

The libraries are: https://github.com/jsantell/dancer.js and http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/42/audio-visualization-with-web-audio-canvas-and-the-soundcloud-api

However, they do not seem to work in mobile. Is there a way you could integrate these into an app? Or is the support for some of the tech these make use of now supported yet. I have only tested on iOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem as for right now is that the Web Audio API is not supported in mobile other than iOS 6+

Check this:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api

This API is the base for building an audio visualizer.

If you are working with Phonegap you could make part of the application web and the visualizer part native and use ir as a Phonegap plugin. It is justified to do this depending how much % of the application the visualizer is.

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate. Thanks for this. Do you know of other ways I could achieve this? It looks like even Webgl would be off the table. What would apps that are currently making visualizations using? Just objective c? Like: https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/audiogasm-music-visualizer/id301351375?mt=8 Thanks.

Comment: In iOS it's possible because the Web Audio API works and you can process the audio file.
For Android I think you have to do this native, not web.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use the [Intel XDK](http://xdk-software.intel.com/) for this. It allows you to make mobile applications using jQuery/JS/HTML5. Assuming you have all the code, it shouldn't be too difficult to port.

HTH.